# Angular CLI installation on Windows 8.1

Tags: angular, installation, angular-cli

**Installed Versions :**

- node v8.9.4
- npm v5.6.0

I tried

> npm install -g -f angular-cli
> npm install -g @angular/cli

This didn't work.
So, I tried

> npm uninstall @angular/cli 
>  npm cache verify 
>  npm install -g
> @angular/cli

But again installation stops at some line shown in image
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Run **NodeJs command prompt** with Administrative access (**run as admin**) and install the AngularCli by hitting the command -

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Comment: try npm cache clean --force

Answer (score 0):

Run command prompt as administrator and try the command

```
npm install -g -f angular-cli
```

Comment: Did you fix the issue

Comment: I am not getting correct solution, I tried many other solutions too.

Answer (score 0):

It could be because you are behind a corporate firewall.

In this case, you need to set the npm proxy settings

```
npm config set proxy http://proxy.com:port
npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.com:port
```